# how to handle small datasets with large dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dataset, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I have 48 samples which are case and control and 27000 features  for each sample so my matrix is [48 X 27000]and I am using Deep belief networks(DBN) as my algorithm to predict the accuracy of the datasets. but when I load the datasets in DBN my results are random. When ever I run the DBN on those samples with same parameter values it just gives me different accuracy. Is there any reason behind it can any one tell me the reason. Can I concatenate the same dataset multiple times and rerun.? Is there a way to do like that.?concatenating in the sense adding same data set multiple times like 48 + 48 = 96 samples. If concatenating is possible can any one give me reference paper.

Comment: Without more information, I doubt it. Is there a probablistic component to the algorithms, maybe? Can you set a random seed with your software to an identical value every time before rerunning it? If so, you should be the same output. At any rate, I don't think your question can be answered as it stands.

Comment: I don't think 48 samples are any good for a DBN to begin with.

Comment: Lots of features, small number of examples, large number of parameters.... yeah, this is exactly the problem I would expect to find! Get more data, less features, and a simpler model. I wouldn't only try a regression with a two IVs where n=48, let alone such an ornate model!

Comment: @gung I edited my question can you check on that

Comment: @usεr11852 As my dimensions are large I felt DBN will handle better than other algorithm.How about SVM ..?? will that work .??

Comment: If you "classify" I would recommend trying classification trees (or forests) first but yeah SVM are valid. Also I would probably PCA that feature vector. :)

Comment: @usεr11852 can you explain me with little more details. ??

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @usεr11852  would probably PCA that feature vector

Comment: yeap, I would probably do a Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on that feature vector to get the principal modes of variation. I would then use the associated scores as surrogate data. Check what principal component regression is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have, is not a problem suitable for DBN. There is no way not to overfit those data. You need to use linear and strongly regularized models. Linear SVM are often used. There is whole chapter in elements of statistical learning about dealing with similar problems, you might check it out (it's for free).

Edit:
whole point of MLP and DBN is that they can learn complex, nonlinear features from the data. You don't have enough data, therefore any method that allow complex models, will just overfit.

Another issue is that in such a high dimensional problem, there is always some hyperplane that can separate your classes, therefore there is no need for nonlinear methods.

Comment: You mean to say DBN will not work for the problem what I have now.? how about MLP will that help.?